# Embedded Linux System Update Application

Tags: embedded-linux, updates

I want to write an application software to update an embedded linux system. It is not well known one, MT2712. I have no experience about embedded linux devices but I have to write an application to update it's firmware. We will use A/B update mechanism. My application will be written in c++. I know that yocto is used to get software image and other parts I need but I don't know where to start, How to take control when USB have an image. I need a help about this topic. I researched there are some open source projects such as mender,swupdate but we won't use them. I have to write it on my own. We won't use OTA, we will upgrade the system via USB.

I have written a template code below, but don't know how to do them.

```
void update_start()
{
    update_progress_status_set(Update_progress_status::started);

    m_update_file = update_file_check();

    if (m_update_file)
    {
        m_update_partition = update_partition_get();

        update_settings_backup();

        m_image_get = image_get();

        m_image_verify = image_verify();

        m_memory_flash = memory_flash();

        if(m_memory_flash)
        {
            update_reboot();
        }
        else
        {
            m_update_failure_status = Update_failure_status::flash_memory_failure;

            update_failure();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        m_update_failure_status = Update_failure_status::update_file_failure;

        update_failure();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it that you can't use any existing body of software to handle most of this for you?

Comment: Actually I have suggested mender.io, swupdate and rauc. They left this decision to me. I don't know how to compare them and which one is most convenient for our system. I may also get a help about this topic.